# Android Tabs/Fragments lifecycle

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabhost

As far as tabs/fragments go, is it possible for them to retain information? For example, if I had a tab that upon the first selection made an http call and then displayed information, could I then have it display the information again upon selection without making another http call?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes.

There are two ways to use tabs in Android. You can use a TabActivity, or a TabHost. Since you mentioned fragments, you are most likely thinking of a TabHost. However, I'll include a description of both just in case:

### TabHost:

Since all of your fragments are contained within a single activity, when navigating between tabs, none of the lifecycle events are fired for the fragment you are navigating away from, so data is persistant whether you want it to be or not.

### TabActivity:

This is where it gets a little trickier. Clicking on a new tab actually stops the old activity, clearing much of your data. The best way to keep any particular data is to place it in a *Singleton*, or an [Application object](http://portabledroid.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/singletons-in-android/). This is a class that extends Application the same way your Activity classes extend Activity. All other activities then have access to this class, which you can give standard getters/setters for any data you'd like.

If you have a great deal of data you'd like to save, you may want to look into creating an [SQLite](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) database, as it will save on memory.